# Getting CROS domain issues while calling one of our local service in Buildfire

Tags: buildfire

I`m trying to access one of our local APIs with buildfire.js
and getting cross domain error
is this something I need to overcome using a configuration in buildfire.js ?

I have already allowed CROS in my local service

Comment: if you already allow in service then what is issue

Comment: it is enabled in the service with "<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />" in web config however, still from the client side, I receive the error

Comment: then most probably not setup properly

Comment: I agree. I've seen this many times. Its the API server refusing cross-domain access. You can test this outside of BuildFire. Mind you, this is upheld completely by the browser so testing using localhost may give you a false positive